# mysql update off by one character

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am using mysql and in the table 'items' updates on the variable image_url 'succeed' with no warnings. But, in reality, the update is failing: it prepends the value with a space and deletes the last character of the value I give it.

Here is the update:

```
UPDATE items
    SET image_url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg'
    WHERE id=38;
```

Here is the select:

```
select * from items\G;
```

Here is one line of the output:

```
...
image_url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
...
```

notice the missing 'g' at the end and the extra space at the beginning.

How do I stop this?

Here is some system info that may help:

```
mysql> show variables LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.46                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | i686                    |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 1** Table description:

```
mysql> desc items;

+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
...
| image_url   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
```

**EDIT 2** Checking for triggers:

```
mysql> show triggers \G
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 3** Another example:

I am doing all these commands from command line. Another example:

```
UPDATE items SET image_url = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg33333333333333' WHERE id=38;

select * from items\G;

...
image_url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg3333333333333
...
```

**EDIT 4** Checking length of inputs and outputs:

```
mysql> select image_url,length(image_url) from items where id=38\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        image_url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
length(image_url): 61
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

http://www.lettercount.com/ gives [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL.*SX522*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg) 61 characters as well, which makes sense given that the update is not changing the length of the string, just deleting the last characters and adding a space to the beginning,

**EDIT 5** Trying encoding:

base64 encoding:
aHR0cDovL2VjeC5pbWFnZXMtYW1hem9uLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvSS82MUR6NXQ4d2pRTC5fU1g1MjJfLmpwZw==

```
mysql> UPDATE items SET image_url = 'aHR0cDovL2VjeC5pbWFnZXMtYW1hem9uLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvSS82MUR6NXQ4d2pRTC5fU1g1MjJfLmpwZw==' WHERE id=38;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select image_url,length(image_url) from items where id=38\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        image_url:  aHR0cDovL2VjeC5pbWFnZXMtYW1hem9uLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvSS82MUR6NXQ4d2pRTC5fU1g1MjJfLmpwZw=
length(image_url): 84
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

decoding: aHR0cDovL2VjeC5pbWFnZXMtYW1hem9uLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvSS82MUR6NXQ4d2pRTC5fU1g1MjJfLmpwZw=

gives:
`http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg`

**EDIT 6** Checking if Insert fails as well:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO items (url, image_url) VALUES('http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg', 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jpg');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.03 sec)
```

the warnings are because I did not give all the values where NULL:NO values in this insert

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value |
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'updated_at' doesn't have a default value |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select image_url,length(image_url),url from items where id=39\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        image_url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
length(image_url): 61
              url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, it also fails on insert.

**EDIT 7** create table information

```
mysql> show create table items\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: items
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `image_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `store` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_items_on_id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_items_on_url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

**EDIT 8** More table and column information

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='items' and column_name='image_url'\G;

*************************** 2. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: def
            TABLE_SCHEMA: development_database
              TABLE_NAME: items
             COLUMN_NAME: image_url
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 5
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: NO
               DATA_TYPE: varchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 255
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 765
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: NULL
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: utf8
          COLLATION_NAME: utf8_unicode_ci
             COLUMN_TYPE: varchar(255)
              COLUMN_KEY: 
                   EXTRA: 
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT: 
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

**EDIT 9** Charlength readouts

```
mysql> select image_url,length(image_url),char_length(image_url),url from items where id=39\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             image_url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
     length(image_url): 61
char_length(image_url): 61
                   url:  http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Dz5t8wjQL._SX522_.jp
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

**EDIT 10** showing variables like character

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 11: THE POTENTIAL ISSUE**

The error does not appear in the users table, but it does occur in the items table. Here is the difference that I think may be causing the issue. (I do not yet have a solution since the item table has that UTF-8 for a reason: urls can have some funky characters)

```
show create table users\G;

ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

show create table items\G;

ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: All of the rows in **EDIT 10** which reference `latin1` or `utf8` should be the same, and ideally should be `utf8mb4` . I would now hazard a guess that the saving of UTF-8 characters in a non-true-utf-8 character collation is meaning the final character of any string is an incomplete reference and so not displaying.

Comment: For your info `utf8mb4` is the full and complete UTF-8 set and so will show any and every character that can be used in a web address. If there are some obscure characters in the data I suggest you change the column to a  `BLOB` column *before* then changing it to a `utf8mb4`, because this will preserve the correct character definitions *as input* rather than *as assumed by MySQL* on the data already entered.

Comment: No, you do not want utf8, in MySQL that is as good as broken, what you want is `utf8mb4`, the standard UTF8 definition in MySQL is rubbish and not what you want.

Comment: you are correct: if you add: ALTER TABLE items CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  as the solution i'll accept it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100620/discussion-on-question-by-rorschach-mysql-update-off-by-one-character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To be honest I think this should be a Community Answer, as I was a
>   little later on the scene and others had done some important ground work
>   establishing what was and was not a factor in this issue.

[This link may be relevant](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), as your table character set is `utf8` so the last character in the string may be getting skewed (and not saving correctly, thus disappearing).

All of the rows in **EDIT 10** which reference `latin1` or `utf8` character set collations should be the same, and ideally should be `utf8mb4` . I would now hazard a guess that the saving of UTF-8 characters in a non-true-utf-8 character collation is meaning the final character of any string is an incomplete reference and so not displaying.

So to solve your issue run the command:

```
ALTER TABLE items CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

---

For info / background:

`utf8mb4` is the full and complete UTF-8 character set and so will show any and every character that can be used in a web address. If there are some obscure characters in the data I suggest you change the column to a `BLOB` column *before* then changing it to a `utf8mb4` column, because this will preserve the correct character definitions *as input* rather than *as assumed by MySQL* on the data already entered.

You do not want `utf8_` character sets, in MySQL that is as good as broken, what you want is `utf8mb4`, the standard UTF8 definition in MySQL is compromised because it saves 4-byte characters in 3-byte blocks and thus corrupts saved character data.